# Display matched string to end of line

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, cut

How to find a particular string in a file and display matched string and rest of the line?

For example- I have a line in `a.txt`:

```
This code gives ORA-12345 in my code.
```

So, I am finding string 'ORA-'

Output Should be:

```
ORA-12345 in my code
```

Tried using grep:

```
grep 'ORA-*' a.txt
```

but it gives whole line in the output.

Comment: Using `grep` - `grep -o -E 'ORA-[0-9]+'`. Using `sed` - `sed -n 's/^.*\(ORA-[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create test data:
echo "junk ORA-12345 more stuff" > a.tst
echo "junk ORB-12345 another stuff" >> a.tst
# Actually command:
# the -o (--only-matching) flag will print only the matched result, and not the full line
cat a.tst | grep -o 'ORA-.*$' # ORA-12345 more stuff
```

As fedorqui pointed out you can use:

```
grep -o 'ORA-.*$' a.tst
```

Comment: note `cat file | grep ...` is not necessary, you can directly say `grep ... file`.

Answer (score 0):

An additional answer in awk:

```
awk '$0 ~ "ORA" {print substr($0, match($0, "ORA"))}' a.tst
```

From the inside out, here's what's going on:

`match($0, "ORA")` finds where in the line `ORA` appears.  In this case, it happens to be position 17.

`substr($0, match($0, "ORA"))` then returns from position 17 to the end of the line.

`$0 ~ "ORA"` makes sure that the the above is applied only to those lines that contain `ORA`.

Comment: Wouldn't `/ORA/` and `$0 ~ "ORA"` be the same?

Comment: This could be simplified to: `i = index($0, "ORA") { print substr($0, i) }`.

Comment: @dev-null, yup, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
echo "This code gives ORA-12345 in my code." | sed 's/.*ORA-/ORA-/'
```